# How to add extra parameter to Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, predicate, unit-of-work

I'm using generic repository and I need to add extra parameter in one of the repository methods. For instance I have isDeleted column on database, I want to add this column as false to predicate.
How can I add extra parameter to predicate from repository method? This extra parameter is fixed for all tables. (isDeleted = false)

This is my original method which is getting single record from db.

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(expression).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This is updated version to add extra parameter I came so far.

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> extra = d => d.GetType().GetProperty("isDeleted").Equals(false);
    var exp = Expression.And(expression.Body, extra.Body);

    var body = Expression.And(expression.Body, extra.Body);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, extra.Parameters);

    return _dbSet.Where(lambda).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

But this updated version gives lambda body like this and ofcouse it's not working.

```
((d.ID == value(ProjectName.Namespace.Controllers.ControllerName).User.CompanyId) And d.GetType().GetProperty("isDeleted").Equals(Convert(False)))
```

Comment: i don't have the code to hand, however, in the past i've used a technique of the Id column on tables (where every table has this column/property). I created an interface which contained on the `int Id {set; get;}`. I then added this interface onto all table class definitions. In my repostitory code, I put a constraint on the `T` type to say this it must contain this interface too. Then in my code i was able to infer the Id property from my type `T'. i know this sounds a ramble, but hopefully you get the gist!!

Comment: I just don't get repositories like this, EF is already a repository and all they seem to do is make life more complicated and remove functionality. For example that method can't eager load with Include. Its not like realistically you can swap out EF for another tech with them.

Comment: @Mant101, I'm currently working on a project where EF has to be replaced with web service calls. If the original developers would have used repositories back then my life would be much easier right now.

Comment: @Abbondanza there are good ways to abstract out the data layer (mediator pattern for example), repository pattern on EF like this is not it. You can't really take a method call like in the example that takes an Expression and just re-impliment it on top of a webservice. Even if you are really lucky and have OData so you have an IQueryable the set of valid expressions are not the same.

Comment: @Mant101, oh I see now that you meant this particular kind of repository. Well then I take back my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public T GetSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    var @params = expression.Parameters;
    var checkNotDeleted = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(@params[0], "isDeleted"), Expression.Constant(false));

    var originalBody = expression.Body;

    var fullExpr = Expression.And(originalBody, checkNotDeleted);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(fullExpr, @params);

    return _dbSet.Where(lambda).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Once you start using `Expression`'s methods, you need to *always use them* (except for `Expression.Constant`, of course). All logic and code you write must be represented with Expression nodes.

There's a method `PropertyOrField` which reads the value of a property from a particular expression. In this case, we're reading it from the parameter (that is, `d => d.isDeleted` - we're writing the `d.isDeleted` part). Then we need to compare the value to false.

Finally, we simply `And` the original expression to ours, and create a lambda with the original parameters.

Comment: Awesome, than you very much.

Comment: @Kadir Sorry, I noticed a mistake in the logic - it should be `Expression.Equal` not `Expression.NotEqual`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), in particular the "Generic Predicates" section that explains how to create generic constraints to filter your items

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `BaseEntity` which contains `IsDeleted` property.

All the other entities should be child of this `BaseEntity`.

Now in the Repository,

```
public class Repository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
....
}
```

And in the query, you can add expression for `IsDeleted` also.

Please have a look here: [Generic Repository Pattern - Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC and Unit Testing Triangle](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle)

Comment: this is a similar technique to what I described in my comment to the OP. In  my case, I used an interface - plus one tho!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change method to:

```
public T GetSingle(param Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] expression)
```

Use array, and key word **param**.

Than you can send two, three, four or what ever number of parameters you want.

Comment: Not helpful. Asker doesn't want to change the method signature. He wants the method to check `isDeleted` on *each* call without the client knowing about this at all.